# How to save the result of Wshshell.sendkeys to a text file?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am not a programmer at all, but just want to write a WSH script for daily network administration tasks from Windows platform. My script is below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile
Dim strRhost

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\swlist.txt", 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strRhost = objFile.ReadLine
    WshShell.Run "putty.exe -ssh " & Chr(34) & strRhost & Chr(34) & " -l admin -pw admin")
    WScript.Sleep 3000
    WshShell.SendKeys "enable{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 100
    WshShell.SendKeys "password{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys ("show clock{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 1500
    WshShell.SendKeys ("show version{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 1500
    WshShell.SendKeys ("show run{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 1500
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
Loop

objFile.Close
WScript.Quit
```

The above script works fine, but how can I output the results of all results to screen and a text file?

Comment: look into the use of `plink` instead of `putty`

Comment: thks Dave, but 1. Plink can not transfer all results completely to the destination ( I tested ). 2. Plink hangs up sometimes while running multi-commands ( and sometimes exit the devices unexpectedly).